# What the buildpack should i add for the nested attributes to make it work in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem, buildpack

What the buildpack should i add for the link_to_add_association to make it work in heroku?

for some reason the `gem cocoon` works locally but not working in heroku
Someone mention to add buildpack to my heroku and I beilive that this is the issue because I did everything right

What buildpack should I add?
I tried this one `https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git` after ruby buildpack but without no luck

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify: how did you include the cocoon javascript code? Did you use webpack or the asset pipeline? (from your earlier question it seems you use the asset pipeline?) How did you include the js code in your html? Do you see any javascript errors in your browsers webconsole? (aka the code is loaded but another error is blocking it?)

Comment: @nathanvda Not sure! All my code are here. I almost give up but your answer gave me some hope

Comment: @nathanvda by  yarn add cocoon-js and inside applicatio.js import 'cocoon-js';